# JQuery constantly fire hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the hover function to fire constantly while the mouse is over the div currently I am using this but it fires only once. It monitors where the mouse is and says whether it is in section 1 or 2.

```
  $(".rating-image").mouseover(function(e){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
    where=(e.clientX - offset.left);
    if(where<=28){alert('1');}
    if(where>28){alert('2');}
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried `mousemove`?

Comment: Seems like you could use `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` and it wouldn't require `.offset()` hackery.

Comment: @CaptainCarl if you put that as an answer i will accept it thank you!

Comment: Question `hover` example `mouseover`. Plz change one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `mousemove` will do the trick!